# How to find if HTML elements EXIST by ID and input different CONTENT

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml, getelementbyid, exists

Thanks in advance for your help.

I have 50 webpages and each page contains several products-elements from the following list:

```
<span id="supS"></span>
<span id="supM"></span>
<span id="supL"></span>
<span id="supX"></span>
<span id="lotS"></span>
<span id="lotM"></span>
<span id="lotL"></span>
<span id="lotX"></span>
<span id="marS"></span>
<span id="marM"></span>
<span id="marL"></span>
<span id="marX"></span>
```

I use these elements to pull the prices from `<script>`:

```
document.getElementById("supS").innerHTML="100";
document.getElementById("supM").innerHTML="250";
document.getElementById("supL").innerHTML="400";
document.getElementById("supX").innerHTML="750";
document.getElementById("lotS").innerHTML="10";
document.getElementById("lotM").innerHTML="25";
document.getElementById("lotL").innerHTML="40";
document.getElementById("lotX").innerHTML="75";
document.getElementById("marS").innerHTML="55";
document.getElementById("marM").innerHTML="70";
document.getElementById("marL").innerHTML="85";
document.getElementById("marX").innerHTML="99";
```

I have to use all IDs on all pages even if i don't have all products, but the code won't work if i don't have everything as you understand.

So i also use another list in which i mention which IDs should be displayed:

```
document.getElementById("supS").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("supM").style.display = "none";
// document.getElementById("supL").style.display = "none";
// document.getElementById("supX").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("lotS").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("lotM").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("lotL").style.display = "none";
// document.getElementById("lotX").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("marS").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("marM").style.display = "none";
// document.getElementById("marL").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("marX").style.display = "none";
```

My **goal** is to have only available products-elements in HTML, remove unavailable from every page (which i'll do manually);

And to use **JavaScript** to:

1. check if product-element exists in HTML by ID;
2. change the price if exists;
3. if not then check another product from the list;
4. change the price if exists;
5. if not then stop checking.

Here i need **your help** to create a JS function.

If it's possible please use the elements and prices mentioned above in your example so i could understand, i'd really appreciate it.

Many thanks.

Comment: What did you try on your own?

Comment: Would it not be easier/cleaner to just append the requierd `span` to the DOM, since you set the *prices* anyway?

Comment: I tried many functions which i found here yesterday from similar questions but unfortunately it didn't work. Let me try to find the code i used. And what do you think i should try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop and test.

Solution if you have less spans than data

```js
const data = {
  "supS": 100,
  "supM": 250,
  "supL": 400,
  "supX": 750,
  "lotS": 10,
  "lotM": 25,
  "lotL": 40,
  "lotX": 75,
  "marS": 55,
  "marM": 70,
  "marL": 85,
  "marX": 99
}
Object.entries(data).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  const span = document.getElementById(k);
  if (span) span.innerText = v;
})
```

```html
<span id="supS"></span>
<span id="supM"></span>
<span id="supL"></span>
<span id="supX"></span>
<span id="marS"></span>
<span id="marM"></span>
<span id="marL"></span>
<span id="marX"></span>
```

Solution if you have more spans than data:

```js
const data = {
  "supS": 100,
  "lotX": 75,
  "marS": 55,
  "marM": 70,
  "marL": 85,
  "marX": 99
};
[...document.querySelectorAll("span")].forEach(span => span.innerText = data[span.id] || "N/A");
```

```html
<span id="supS"></span>
<span id="supM"></span>
<span id="supL"></span>
<span id="supX"></span>
<span id="marS"></span>
<span id="marM"></span>
<span id="marL"></span>
<span id="marX"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand why you do not create fields according to the stock status but may be this will help you:

```
var arrProduct = []; // I assume you get a json like that from server side [{"ProductName": "supS", "AvailStock": 3, "Price": 2.35}, {"ProductName": "lotM", "AvailStock": 0, "Price": 0}]
    for (var i = 0; i < arrProduct.length; i++) {
        if (arrProduct[i].AvailStock > 0){
            document.getElementById(arrProduct[i].ProductName).innerHTML = arrProduct[i].Price;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(arrProduct[i].ProductName).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```